# How to lock View after ObjectAnimation?

Tags: java, android

I want to lock my `ImageView` after executing the animation. How can I do that?

After this code I want the View to stay in this position so when I call another animation it will start from that position and not from the original place it's declared in XML.

```
float x = (float) widthPerTab / 2;
objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(slider, "x", widthPerTab + x);
objectAnimator.setDuration(300);
objectAnimator.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Using `ViewPropertyAnimator`

```
float x = (float) widthPerTab / 2;

ViewPropertyAnimator animator = slider.animate()
        .translationXBy(widthPerTab + x)
        .setDuration(300);
animator.start();
```

**Solution 2:** Using `ObjectAnimator`

```
float x = (float) widthPerTab / 2;

ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(slider,
        View.TRANSLATION_X,
        slider.getTranslationX() + x)
        .setDuration(300);
animator.start();
```

Comment: what's the difference between ObjectAnimator and ViewPropertyAnimator?

Comment: ViewPropertyAnimator is built on top of ObjectAnimator, it enables better performance and easy to use.

Comment: @purity6666 if you still want to use `ObjectAnimator`, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```java
objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(slider, "translationX", widthPerTab + x);
```

just change the String constant from "x" to "translationX" or Y if you want the vertical axis